# get href onclick and redirect with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do below code for redirect from one page to other page with that particular 'a' tag click and appended with that particular link which is in clk variable

```js
function abc()
{
 
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
//alert(a);
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       a[i].onclick = function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
  var clk=$(this).attr('href');
  window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com?ver='+clk;
       //doSomething();
    }
}
}
```

```html
<a  id="first" onclick='abc();' href="http://www.google.com" >Google</a><br/>
<a  id="second" onclick='abc();' href="http://www.yahoo.com" >Yahoo</a><br/>
<a  id="third" onclick='abc();' href="http://www.rediff.com" >Rediff</a><br/>
<a  id="third" onclick='abc();' href="http://www.gmail.com" >Gmail</a><br/>
<a  id="third" onclick='abc();' href="http://www.facebook.com" >Facebook</a><br/>
```

The above code is not work properly that i want

e.g. suppose when i click on first link(or may be some other) then on that particular click i get href of that link and store in clk variable and also redirect to other page with that particular link.

Comment: have you added jquery in your code?

Comment: yes i added in same page

Comment: can you share a fiddle in that case? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This code is working fine in my computer, may I know what is not working for you ? Is it the redirection to other page ?

Comment: It's workin fine thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need use loop to add `onclick` event because you are using inline event `onclick`, also you can get `href` with method `getAttribute`

```js
function abc(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href')
  window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com?ver=' + href;
}
```

```html
<a id="first" onclick='abc(event);' href="http://www.google.com" >Google</a><br/>
<a id="second" onclick='abc(event);' href="http://www.yahoo.com" >Yahoo</a><br/>
<a id="third" onclick='abc(event);' href="http://www.rediff.com" >Rediff</a><br/>
<a id="fourth" onclick='abc(event);' href="http://www.gmail.com" >Gmail</a><br/>
<a id="fifth" onclick='abc(event);' href="http://www.facebook.com" >Facebook</a>
```

however if in your project there is jQuery you can solve this issue like this

```js
$('a.redirect').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href')
  window.location='http://www.shopeeon.com?ver=' + href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="redirect" id="first" href="http://www.google.com" >Google</a><br/>
<a class="redirect" id="second" href="http://www.yahoo.com" >Yahoo</a><br/>
<a class="redirect" id="third" href="http://www.rediff.com" >Rediff</a><br/>
<a class="redirect" id="fourth" href="http://www.gmail.com" >Gmail</a><br/>
<a class="redirect" id="fifth" href="http://www.facebook.com" >Facebook</a>
```

**Note** - `id` **must** be unique

Comment: Both of above are working properly Thank you so much for your valuable support