# Get href on click and redirect with shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working with this idea:
[get href onclick and redirect with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541560/get-href-onclick-and-redirect-with-link)
Because i need a link redirect to another page.

My problem is that the second page is dinamic. For it, i use a shortcode. But im not know how i can do for it works.
The var yourHTML is not working.

```
 <?php 
 function links_redirect() {
 global $activities_template, $bp;$activity_id;
 $activity_id = bp_get_activity_id();
 $user_id = bp_get_activity_user_id();
 $redirectLink= $user_id. '/test/' . $activity_id;
 return  $redirectLink;
 }

add_shortcode('link_shortcode', 'links_redirect');
?>

<script>
function abc(event) {
var yourHTML = '<?php do_shortcode("[link_shortcode]"); ?>';
var href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
window.location='example.com?ver=' + yourHTML;

}
</script>

<a id="first" onclick='abc(event);' href="<?php echo $variblefuncionando;?>" >Ver</a>
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: Hi!  The var yourHTML is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `event.preventDefault();` to cancel the default redirection

```
function abc(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  .....
}
```

Comment: thanks Indra! I added your code and "echo" ` yourHTML = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[link_shortcode]"); ?>';`